# If I want to sell zero coupon bond before maturity what will it be the price for it?

Tags: finance

Let's say I have 10yrs ZCB with a yield of 3% I hold the bond for one year what will be the price for my bond if I want to sell it ? thank you for the help.

Comment: That depends on the prevailing interest rates at the time of sale.

Comment: after one year let's say the 10years yield are at 2,90% and the 9years yield is at 2,7% would this help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  I thought the $10$-year bond yields $3\%$.  What is this $2.9\%$?  I also don't understand the second sentence.  The price of the bond (before commissions or other costs of sale) is the present value of the principal in $9$ years, calculated at prevailing interest rates.

Comment: what do you mean by prevailing interest rates ? is it the 9 years yield ?

Comment: The prevailing interest rate is the rate at which the market is pricing similar bonds at the moment.  I have already said I don't understand what you mean the "$9$ years yield."  If it is the rate used to price $9$-year zero-coupon bonds of similar creditworthiness one year after the purchase of the original bond, then yes it it is.  That's a lot to read into the phrase "$9$ years yield" though.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more clear about it : after one year let's say the 10 years yield of ZCB is 2,90% and the 9 years yield Zero coupon bond is 2,7%, If I want to sell the ZC Bond I bought at 3% yield after one year, my bond will it be worth 100/(1+2,7%)^9 ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for the help :)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price is whatever the market will pay for it.  If the value at maturity is $1000$, the original price $P$ should have had $P\cdot 1.03^{10}=1000$ or $P \approx 744.04$.  After one year at $3\%$ it would nominally be worth $1.03$ times as much or $766.42$.  If interest rates have risen in the meantime, say to $4\%$ the new value $V$ would have $V\cdot 1.04^9=1000$ for $V\approx 702.59$.  If interest rates have fallen it will be worth more.

Comment: 4% are the yield of 9 years bond right ?

Comment: That is right.  We derive the price by assuming the prevailing interest rate, just as I did for the original price of the bond.  Of course, the market may believe that interest rates will rise further and not be willing to pay even this much.

Comment: Thank you for your help